# Javascript Issues with Sharepoint 2010 and external CSS files

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

In Sharepoint 2010, I'm starting with the default master page and adding 1 external css file (the issue only seems to exist with css files from another domain) using a link tag. This does change the style correctly, however if I try to add a new announcement and select the main text box, the ribbon controls become unresponsive. If I open the network tab in firebug, I can see that Sharepoint is constantly using an XMLHttpRequest to request the external css file I added. Is there anybody else that can confirm this bug or has any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: If you're seeing it in Firebug, doesn't that indicate that your **browser**, and not SharePoint, is requesting the CSS file? Also, since you are likely using Firefox if you're using Firebug, does the problem happen when you use a different browser, like IE or Chrome?

Comment: @CBono Yes, I was using firefox, but the issue occurs in other browsers as well. It causes all the other javascript (like the ribbon) to become unresponsive because it seems like there is an infinite loop in there somewhere. I ended up fixing the issue by overriding one of sharepoint's javascript functions, but that's hardly an elegant solution. I'm interested to see if this issue affects anybody else or if it is some configuration issue on my end. I got the issue if I included css from another domain and focused a textbox that lets you change your font. That would freeze the ribbon.